# Unable to create a Specific coupon code in magento using REST API

Tags: magento, coupon

I am trying to create a specific Coupon code for Magento using API REST
I am able to create random coupon code using but i want a specific coupon like HOLI100. How to achieve that

API(URL/rest/V1/coupons/generate)

```
{
    "couponSpec": {
        "rule_id":254,
        "quantity": 1,
        "length": 7,    // character length of coupon excluding prefix/suffix. ie = EY-QRF7J-WA
        "prefix": "HOLI",
        "suffix": "100"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `POST /rest/V1/coupons/generate` API endpoint is used to auto-generate coupon codes based on a template. In order to add a specific coupon you need to use `POST /rest/V1/coupons` endpoint. But there is a couple of things you should keep in mind:

1. When adding a specific coupon code, you can have only 1 code per sales rule.
2. In order to add a specific coupon, the related sales rule must have coupon_type = 2.

Based on the information above, you should do the following API requests:

1. **Update coupon_type attribute for the sales rule:**

   ```
   PUT /rest/V1/salesRules/254
   {
       "rule": {
           "coupon_type": "2"
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Add a specific coupon code to this rule:**

   ```
   POST /rest/V1/coupons
   {
       "coupon": {
           "rule_id": 254,
           "code": "HELI100",
           "usage_limit": 0,
           "usage_per_customer": 0,
           "is_primary": true,
           "type": 0
       }
   }
   ```

Here is the result:
[image]